# Equivalent of the French expression "Mais de là à ..."

Tags: выражения, французский

In conversation, you can say, for instance:

> Elle était du genre à se jeter sur les horoscopes. **Mais de là à** se faire refaire les lignes de la main...

- "*She was always one to blindly believe in astrology, but to go through a surgery to have her palm lines changed...*"

"*Mais de là à + inf.*" is a very *French* expression that doesn't translate easily into other languages. It has the literal meaning of "***But from there to*** (doing something much more extreme)", denoting the drastic shift from A to B, and is used to emphasise that someone has apparently done something extremely surprising/appalling/etc, even by his/her standards. When this expression is used, the clause tends to end with an ellipsis, making a dangling sentence.

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in Russian?

Answer (score 2):

I remember you used Russian equivalent once in quotes of your Russian utterances

> ..., но чтобы пойти на операцию по изменению линий на руке?..

or it can be expressed without the rhetorical question

> ..., но не настолько/не до такой (же) степени, чтобы пойти/идти на
>   операцию по изменению линий на руке.

Comment: Indeed. I'm looking for other variants, ideally something that conveys the sense of the drastic shift from A to B: "*But **from there to** ...*". I'm not sure if "делать из этого вывод", for instance, can work.

Answer (score 2):

Mais de là à se faire refaire les lignes de la main...

Наиболее разговорный вариант:

> Но,  чтобы пойти на операцию по изменению линий на руке — это уже слишком.(It's too far)

Нейтральный:(to the extent of)

> но не до такой же степени,  чтобы пойти...